# Any way to reduce the time taken in Starting and Stopping the worker pool in Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

As the part of performance analysis of my load job on Dataflow, I noticed that it usually takes around 2 minutes to start the worker pool and after successful load it takes another 2 minutes in stopping the worker pool.
So, if my entire process takes 10 minutes to complete then out of those 10 minutes there are about 5 minutes which is taken in starting and stopping the worker pool.

Is there any way which allows to reduce this configuration time which is acting as an overhead in my load process? Please suggest.

Comment: Please specify which SDK you use.

Comment: Apache Beam SDK for Java 2.2.0/2.1.0 @MarcinZablocki

Comment: There is a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317202/optimizing-apache-beam-cloud-dataflow-startup/54319387#54319387