# Optimizing apache beam / cloud dataflow startup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have done a few tests with apache-beam using both auto-scale workers and 1 worker, and each time I see a startup time of around 2 minutes. Is it possible to reduce that time, and if so, what are the suggested best practices for reducing the startup time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO: Two minutes is very fast for a product like Cloud Dataflow. Remember, Google is launching a powerful Big Data service for you that autoscales.

Compare that time to the other cloud vendors. I have seen some clusters (Hadoop) take 15 minutes to come live. In any event, you do not control the initialization process for Dataflow so there is nothing for you to improve.

Comment: what about putting it into "streaming" mode? Does that solve the issue?

Comment: What issue? If you mean to have the Dataflow cluster running at all times in streaming mode, how does that improve your startup time? Streaming means that Dataflow is reading from unbounded data sources (data that never ends). Batch and Streaming modes require different code designs in Dataflow.

Comment: thanks for the response. What I mean is, if it's in 'streaming' mode it would essentially be "on" all the time, right? In this case, we wouldn't have to worry about ever 'turning on' the DF runners, because they would already be on. Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: In streaming mode, Dataflow would already be running a job that is designed to run forever. If you want a cluster that is sitting idle waiting for jobs, look at Dataproc. Dataflow does not launch and then wait for jobs. You launch Dataflow as a job.

Comment: Cloud Dataflow is designed to be `serverless` in the same context that Cloud Functions is `serverless`. Dataflow does not launch and then sit there idle. Just like other serverless products, it launches when you need it and then shuts down. For long running clusters that process jobs ad-hoc, you should pick a different service. Cloud Dataflow is Cloud Dataproc with Spark (Hadoop + Spark) running as a managed service. This is why I am so impressed with how fast Google can launch Dataflow. Hadoop takes a long time to startup and get all of its services ready.

Comment: thanks for the response. Would it be ok if I reached out to you (on your website) about working/consulting on the above project?

Comment: Yes, please contact me.

Comment: great, just messaged.

Comment: Sorry, a little late to the party. I am running into a very similar issue and would love to know the solution you worked out for clusters that process jobs ad-hoc.